# need suggestions about how to parse two values with same key from json format into java map

Tags: java, hashmap, ldap

I'm working on reading ldif attributes from LDAP into my java program, my original thought is to put those attributes in to a map, then parse them from it, but I found that, there is an attributes call "departmentNumber", which contains two json format values,

```
departmentNumber: {"sid":"729999","uid":501,"name":"tebase","role":"managers","title":"sales","groups":["others"]}
departmentNumber: {"sid":"724605","uid":37,"name":"tebase","role":"managers","title":"develope","groups":["leaders"]}
```

so I used map to put them, some codes shown below,

but my way can only retrieve the 1st json value, which is the one that contains {"sid":"729999"}, but no 2nd value that contains {"sid":"724605"},

I observed the program log is:

#### this is the log that read from ldif attributes

```
2019 22:30:58,237 authentication.mzauth   authentication.mzauth.doAuthenticate(mzauth.java:44)  
{"uid":"brucelee","mail":"brucelee@gm.macom","displayName":"Bruce Lee","givenName":"Bruce Lee","departmentNumber":"{\"sid\":\"729999\",\"uid\":501,\"name\":\"teabas\",\"role\":\"managers\",\"title\":\"sales\",\"groups\":[\"others\"]}","objectClass":"inetOrgPerson","description":"Bruce Lee","sn":"Bruce Lee","cn":"Z39414","department":"000000","info":"2006/02/12"}
```

#### this is the log that put into a map and parse them out

```
2019 22:30:58,247 services.LdapService services.LdapService.getUser(LdapService.java:251)
ldap user：{"username":"brucelee","fullname":"Bruce Lee","email":"brucelee@gm.macom","departmentid":"729999","titles":[{"schoolid":"729999","titles":["managers","sales"]}],"cloudroles":{"usage":"clouddev","roles":[{"appname":"mail","departmentid":"729999","titles":["managers","sales"]}]},"guid":"c00d5ba660145307c84f2c1e1c557e4ededaf1830029d40aa5b244027","pid":"Z39414","openid":"http://openid.macom/brucelee"}
```

as you can read, there is only 1 value, the one which is sid:72999, instead of two values,

the original ldif attributes is:

> LDAPv3 
>   base  with scope subtree 
>   filter: uid=brucelee 
>   requesting: ALL
>
> > Z39414, Managers, developer.alle.com 
> >     dn: cn=Z39414,ou=Managers,dc=developer,dc=alle,dc=com
> >     uid: brucelee
> >     userPassword: qwdmsdierf
> >     mail: brucelee@gm.macom
> >     info: 2006/02/12
> >     sn: Bruce Lee
> >     departmentNumber: 
> >     {"sid":"729999","uid":501,"name":"tebase","role":"managers","title":"sales","groups":["others"]}
> >     　departmentNumber:
> >     {"sid":"724605","uid":37,"name":"tebase","role":"managers","title":"develope","groups":["leaders"]}
> >     department: 000000
> >     givenName: Bruce Lee
> >     objectClass: inetOrgPerson
> >     objectClass: organizationalPerson
> >     objectClass: person
> >     objectClass: top
> >     cn: Z39414
> >     displayName: Bruce Lee
> >     description: Bruce Lee
>
> search result
>   search: 2
>   result: 0 Success
>   numResponses: 2
>   numEntries: 1

my question is, how can I put both 2 json values into my map, or my usage of map is wrong, and there is a better way to deal with this kind of situation?

```java
public DataModel getUser(String uid, String passwd, String role, DataModel   user) throws Exception {
private Map<String, String> map = null;
   if (role.equals("managers")) {
            map = Ldap.getAttrubites(ldapurl, uid, passwd);
            List<Titles> titlesArray = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Roles> rolesArray = new ArrayList();
            map.forEach((key, value)
                    -> {logger.info("{} - {}", key, value); });
     if (key.equals("departmentNumber")) {
                List<StringModel> model = map.get("departmentNumber")).get();
                model.stream().forEach(k -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
                            Titles titles = new Titles();
                            List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
                            String userid = model.get(i).getUid();
                            String mtitle = model.get(i).getRole();
                            String subtitle = model.get(i).getTitle();
                            titleList.add(mtitle);
                            titleList.add(subtitle);
                            titles.setSchoolid(schoolid);
                            titles.setTitles(titleList);
                            titlesArray.add(titles);

                 ........ });}
                 user.setTitles(titlesArray);
                 .........;
    } return user;
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a JSON parser?

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Map<K,V>` interface holds only one value for each key. If you want to hold multiple values for each key, you need to specify a collection class to the `V` part. For example, like the following.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = ...
```

The `javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap` interface defined in Java EE API is an example that achieves what you want to do.